# a way to know when all callbacks are done in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have many calls to a service at the end of which  i want to write to a file my final collection when all the callbacks of the service have returned.
is there there a way to be sure that all callbacks are done ?

```
for (id in idsCollection) {
    object.callService(id, function (res) {
        collection.push(res);
    });
}

filewriter.writetoFile("filename.json", JSon.Stringify(collection));
```

EDIT : just for the record i'm using cheerio with nodeJS.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: In plain english, decrement a global_total on each callBack completion. call a check() function upon each callback completion that checks that global_total is 0 or not. If it is 0, perform your *special task*

Comment: @georg i'm using cheerio with nodejs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an array. Push something onto the array each time you set up a callback. Pop something off it each time the callback runs. Check to see if the array is empty inside the callback function. If it is empty, then all the callbacks are done.

Comment: Why not increment / decrement a counter?

Comment: You could do that as well. Putting relevant objects on an array gives you more options for inspecting them.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear :D +1

Comment: it sounds good as a solution , but what about node-async ? it seems like a cleaner solution .

Comment: AFAIK, this is (essentially) what node-async does. It's just an answer instead of a product recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I typically use the [node-async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for this sort of thing. It makes it easy to do exactly what you're talking about:

```
async.each(yourArray,
    function(element, next) { 
        // this callback gets called for each element in your array
        element.doSomething(function(returnValue){
            next(returnValue) // call next when you're done
        }
    }, function(err, returnValues) {
        // when all the elements in the array are processed, this is called
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(returnValues) // this is an array of the returnValues
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply count them. In your case it seems you already know how many callbacks there are going to be.

```
var remaining = idsCollection.length; // assuming array
for (id in idsCollection) {
    object.callService(id, function (res) {
        collection.push(res);
        remaining -= 1; // decrement by 1 per callback
        // here you can check if remaining === 0 (all done)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use nimble lib http://caolan.github.io/nimble/.

### nimble paralel example

```
var _ = require('nimble');

_.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('one');
            callback();
        }, 25);
    },
    function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('two');
            callback();
        }, 0);
    }
], function(){
    console.log('done')
});
```

output

```
> two
> one
> done
```

Comment: the number of parallele functions i need to fire in parralele is decided on runtime :)  i can't hardcode each call like that .

Comment: as you can see, the first function parameter is array. push as much function as you want into the array.

Answer (score 2):

I see many answers here, but I hope that this solution may still help someone.

Create a promise for each callback to be extinguished as such:

```
function funcToLoop(arg){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            funcWithCallback(arg, (cbArg) => {
                // do your stuff
                resolve(cbArg)
            });  
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    });
}
```

Then, you can create a loop as a async function and handle eventual results/states/etc here:

```
async function mainLoop(array){

    let results = [];

    for (let arg of array){
        results.push(await funcToLoop(arg))
    }
    // handle results
}
```

... or you can have a sync function, collect the promises and handle them:

```
function mainLoop(array){

    let promises = [];

    for (let arg of array){
        promises.push(funcToLoop(arg))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
        // handle promises
    })
}
```

Claudio

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use `$.when`

Example:

```
exmCall1 = $.getJson(..);
exmCall2 = $.getJson(..);

$.when(exmCall1, exmCall2).done(function (exmCall1Ret, exmCall2Ret) {
    //do stuff
});
```

You can read the actual documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @Cerbrus `object.callWebservice` could be using jquery. Regardless, the answer might help someone coming across this question through google.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) objects might be what you are looking for.

OR if you are using HTML5 you can use `promises` .

Here is how to create promises

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

And here is how to use them

```
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

Check [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) for more info

Comment: thanks man , but just for the record , i'm using server side Javascript with nodejs , and a bit of cheerio as well .

Answer (score 0):

Or do some hardcode:

```
    var running;
    for (id in idsCollection) {
        object.callService(id, function (res) {
            collection.push(res);
            running += 1;
        });
    }

    var loop = setInterval(function() {
    if(running >= idsCollection.length) {
        filewriter.writetoFile("filename.json", JSon.Stringify(collection));
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
    , 500);
```

Comment: Don't start a loop that checks twice every second to see if a callback's done. Check for the condition in the callback itself.